# Zoom Maps do , width and length of the route Android Studio

Tags: java, android, maps, zooming

I am looking for a solution to my problem. My application uses Google Maps and Google Play Service. My application gets the user's position and writes to the array. On the basis of the points I make a route. When I display it on the map, the map is far away. I'd like to bring. The problem is that the route can have a length from 50m to 1000km. Someone please help me ? Thank you very much!

My maps can look as below (BLUE LINE)!

[image: Map]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you already save the user's position, so it's pretty simple. Just pick the first and last positions and use a CameraUpdate to display the route to the user:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(first_position_latlng);
builder.include(last_position_latlng);
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding_if_any);
mMap.animateCamera(cu);
```

Just keep in mind that this works for simple routes like the one you linked. For more complex ones instead of the first and last position, you'll need to find the the furthest southwest and northeast points